# Where are the Fallout 4 screenshots saved?

Tags: fallout-4

I cannot find any file of screen shots in My Document and game folder for Fallout 4. Where are those files?

Comment: @Robotnik Fallout 4 is released quite a while now and I couldn't think of any reason why looking at screenshots one took could be illegal.

Comment: I am kind of confused by this as well @Philipp **Edit** Oh wait looking at the edits kind of explains why it was closed. Also the comments on the answer below.

Comment: @Phillips - OP admitted to piracy (comments on the answer below), and the 'correct' answer apparently does not hold true for the pirated game. To answer it the way OP wants would therefore be to provide technical support for a pirated game, and our policy is quite clear on this topic: we don't support blatant piracy.

Comment: @Robotnik Do not upset yourself! Second answer is correct.I can delete all comment about pirated game! Please do not close my question.It is useful for all gamers even with legal games.

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited I'm glad you got the answer you're looking for, however I won't reopen the question for the reasons stated above. Please understand, this isn't a reflection on you personally, but an upholding of one of the [core off-topic rules](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the site: *"Piracy, and support with pirated games."*

Comment: Note that deleting the aspects about piracy doesn't mean this question is on-topic; it just means you're trying to hide your tracks.  It's still off-topic, regardless.

Comment: @Robotnik I am sorry for you.You are against me behind the rules.You are deceiving yourself.I could accept Shootatme answer without any comment about pirated game and you never can understand my game is copy.Also other people (even with legal games) can use my useful question.Now you are disagree with deleting comment about pirated game.Because you just want playing surveyor game and abuse of power.

Comment: No.  This is not an abuse of power.  This is about *upholding the rules.*  This is piracy, through and through.  We care about helping actual legitimate gamers, not pirates.  If you pirate a game, great!  We don't care.  But don't ask us to help you, because we won't.  By accepting an answer that helps piracy, you're encouraging more of the same here, which is exactly what we don't want.

Comment: Although OP may have not had the ideal setup, this is still a very valuable question to be answered, and [shows up highly on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fallout+4+screenshot+folder). It's worth reopening this question and burninating any mention of unlicensed/illegal practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot should be in the game folder wherever you installed it , something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Fallout 4.

Answer (score 4):

[steam directory]/userdata/[userID number]/760/remote/screenshots/377160

The default Steam directory is C:/Program Files(x86)/Steam, but you may have changed it.

Comment: I have not this folder.I don't use Steam.Steam is not installed in my PC.

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited then, how you actually have installed game? I'm not sure if Fallout 4 has some default folder for screenshots, so it most probably depends on platform you've used to buy game.

Comment: @lentinant I did not buy this game.This is cracked version.

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited then I can't provide answer (neither I'd like to help pirate).

Comment: @lentinant No! I am not pirate! LOL! Iran is restricted and has not copyright rules and there are not any original software and game and buying original games is not possible.Even with additional money. We have to use cracked version or we should forget all games!

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited I mean, you're still a pirate, even if you have no legal recourse. But more importantly, we can't possibly know how exactly the game was cracked, because we weren't the ones who did the cracking. Your screenshots could be anywhere.